# Import YAML file content as ENV in ruby

Tags: ruby, yaml, environment-variables

Working on Ruby Rspec Capybara project. I have different env like

sample yml file

```
dev:
  url: google.com
  user: dev_user
  password: dev_password
test:
  url: google.com
  user: test_user
  password: test_password
```

Think yml would help here.
Is it possible to parse yaml file and store it as ENV variable so that it is available across the project in Ruby

this is purely ruby project. how can we do it without rails credentials

Comment: [`ENV`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/ENV.html) is a class like any other so you can use the methods provided to add or remove variables as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the `dotenv` [gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#sinatra-or-plain-ol-ruby)?

Comment: Tried to use the dotenv gem on yaml files, it did not store as hashes but as strings